# How to convert an IMPORTRANGE() array to a string, for use with QUERY()?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have the same problem which is discussed [here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/2271140/query-function-not-working-with-specific-data-set-but-working-with-others?hl=en), except that I am working with `IMPORTRANGE()` instead of a direct array reference (e.g., `D12:I119`). Somehow I need `QUERY()` to understand its input as an array of strings. But my attempt to addend a null string (`&""`) to `IMPORTRANGE()`, as suggested in the link, doesn't work:

```
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...","Sheet1!A3:1000")&"","select Col1, Col2")
```

How else can I get around this? Unfortunately, I can't change the data on the spreadsheet referenced by `IMPORTRANGE()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...", 
 "Sheet1!A3:1000")), 
 "select Col1, Col2", )
```